# adding a linearlayout to the current view doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am trying to add a linearlayout to a scrolview
this is my code
the code compiles, but it doesn't show me the new layout

this is the original layout (that i want to add to it)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 

android:layout_margin="15dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" 
     android:id="@+id/ViewHistoryImageLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/HistoryImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.76"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/upload" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/HistoryImage"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TranslatedText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.12"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/translateImageButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the layout that i want to add several times:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/TranslationMenuLayout" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the java code for adding the new layout is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_history_image);
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View ll = inflater.inflate(R.layout.translation_menu, null);
sv.addView(ll);
```

the code compiles fine, and the app is running but nothing happens
is there a problem with one of the .xml files?

tnx

Comment: Right now your adding a scrollview layout to a dynamically created scrollview. This is bound to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve existing ScrollView layout instead of creating it.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_history_image);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View ll = inflater.inflate(R.layout.translation_menu, null);
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
sv.addView(ll);
```

might help.

Comment: tnx, but i'm getting the exeption: scrollview can only host direct child

Comment: solved it:
I needed to add the new linearlayout to the linearLayout that was inside the scrollview.

working code:
    LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ViewHistoryImageLayout);
    sv.addView(ll);

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your `layout_width` in your original `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`. It is taking up the whole layout

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I was trying to do this on onSizeChange and it didn't work.
so this code helped me:

```
        layout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getContext());

                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                layout.addView(ll, params);
            }
        }, 100);
```

layout is the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I build different ImageView to make it works, like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.selected_spotphotos_container);
        imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView1 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView2 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg1);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmImg2);
        imageView2.setImageBitmap(bmImg3);

        linearLayout.addView(imageView,0);
        linearLayout.addView(imageView1,1);
        linearLayout.addView(imageView2,2);
```

The XML code is this one:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
....

<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hori_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:foregroundGravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/selected_spotphotos_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            >

            <!-- images will be added dynamicall to this layout -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
//here u can add different EditText or Button or whatever you want
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this can help someone.